# It's not supposed that children equal 2 should be hidden?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this HTML code:

```
<ul id="product_create-header" class="stepy-header">
    <li id="product_create-head-0" class="stepy-active">
        <div>Categoría</div><span>Categoría</span>
    </li>
    <li id="product_create-head-1">
        <div>Producto</div><span>Producto</span>
    </li>
    <li id="product_create-head-2">
        <div>Variaciones</div><span>Variaciones</span>
    </li>
    <li id="product_create-head-3">
        <div>Detalles</div><span>Detalles</span>
    </li>
    <li id="product_create-head-4">
        <div>Condiciones</div><span>Condiciones</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

In order to hide the children element equal to 2 I made this code:

```
$('#product_create-header').children().eq(2).hide();
$('#product_create').find('fieldset').eq(2).hide();
```

But it's not working since "Variaciones" still appearing, what's wrong in my code? See the image attached

[image]

Comment: It works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/5VDHN/

Comment: Looks good to me: http://jsfiddle.net/Sergio_fiddle/Nq6DL/

Comment: @JosephSilber Hmmm something is really rare here since I still getting maybe is the [jQuery plugin](http://wbotelhos.com/stepy) I'm using since I still getting the element displayed, see the image in the main post

Comment: Do you get any console error?

Comment: @Reynier Please post your complete HTML may be ID is repeating.

Comment: @Sergio nop, I didn't

Comment: @Dnyan I checked for that too and is not repeatedly this drive me crazy since I can't find where the problem is

Comment: Do you have a live link?

Comment: @Sergio not, I'm working on localhost, what I can give you is Teamviewer access, please in that case write a email to reynierpm at gmail dot com in order to give you credentials

Comment: what version of jQuery you are using?

Comment: @IrfanTahirKheli latest

Comment: @Reynier may be you are generating that UL after the load. means dynamically you are adding the DOM

Comment: @Dnyan nop, the DIV is generated when page load

Comment: @Reynier Please post your complete HTML/jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Post the result for each command:

```
$('#product_create-header')

$('#product_create-header').children()

$('#product_create-header').children().eq(2)
```

This way you can check wich selector does not work.

And you should call .stepy() inside the $(function() {}); and then call the code I passed to you.

Comment: But what you mean with post the result? Should I use `alert()` or `console.log()` to get this post result?

Comment: The console output. Check my edit answer too.

Comment: I don't know how to send otuput to console other than `console.log()`

Comment: Open firebug and paste the code. If it works on firebug but not on your code, then the problem is loading sequence.

Comment: Ok, here you got the results `>>> $('#product_create-header')
Object[ul#product_create-header.stepy-header]`, `>>> $('#product_create-header').children()
Object[li#product_create-head-0.stepy-active, li#product_create-head-1, li#product_create-head-2, li#product_create-head-3, li#product_create-head-4]` and `>>> $('#product_create-header').children().eq(2)
Object[li#product_create-head-2]`

Comment: I changed my code to `$('#product_create-head-2').hide();         $('#product_create-step-2').hide();` and it works so there is a problem with the previous solution

Comment: If you `$('#default-demo-header').children().eq(1).hide();` or `$('#default-demo').find('fieldset').eq(1).hide();` at http://wbotelhos.com/stepy it works. The problem is on your code. What you said to work, the the same code, but getting the children directly. It is not good, because any change on internal structure will break your script.

Comment: You're right something was wrong in my code since I changed the code to this: `$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#product_create-header').children().eq(2).hide();
        $('#product_create').find('fieldset').eq(2).hide();
    });` and it's working now

Comment: This was my first answer for you by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Try it as following. See this may solve you problem. Not sure though.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#product_create-header').children().eq(2).hide();
    $('#product_create').find('fieldset').eq(2).hide();

});
```

Comment: No, this is not the problem I already try that

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/ ..  You may try this one as well.

Comment: Tested using this `$('#product_create-header:nth-child(2)').fadeOut();` and didn't work either

Comment: Try show it in alert box first. alert($('#product_create-header:nth-child(2)').html()); and see if html is showing in alert box.

Comment: alert($('#product_create-header'));  alert($('#product_create-header:nth-child(2)'));

Comment: $('#product_create-header li:nth-child(2)').hide(); try this one as well